# Selecting a single line using command in windows cmd

Tags: windows-7

I have created a batch file which redirects into a plain text file. What the batch does is goes to the mentioned path and there dir command gets executed and the output will be directed to a text file.

Now when i open the text file i see the whole tree, but i want only one folder when i has been modified last.

So, can any one suggest what is the command that i have to give so that it picks only that folder and prints the same into my text file.

Below is the content of my batch file :

```
S:
cd S:\log\logit-esb\dhl\subscriptions
dir >> D:\Abhi_Work\System_Monitoring\System_monitoring.txt
```

When I run the batch file below is the output directed to my text file.

```
 Directory of S:\log\logit-esb\dhl\subscriptions

05/01/2015  04:25 PM    <DIR>          .
05/01/2015  04:25 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/01/2015  04:25 PM    <DIR>          processed
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)   4,682,932,224 bytes free
 Volume in drive S is System
 Volume Serial Number is 42A7-D3B7
```

My requirement is i want only the below line to be displayed in the output file

```
05/01/2015  04:25 PM    <DIR>          processed
```

SO anyone help me in achieving this.

Comment: @paradroid piping to `findstr` is probably easier than using `for /f` ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Oh yeah, forgot about that.

Answer (score 2):

The following command in your batch file will do what you want:

```
dir | findstr "processed" >> D:\Abhi_Work\System_Monitoring\System_monitoring.txt
```

You should first make sure `System_monitoring.txt` is an empty file as the `>>` will append to the file ...

---

Source [Search for strings in files.](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Piping and Redirection

> A text file can be piped or redirected into FINDSTR:
>
> Data stream from a pipe TYPE file.txt | FINDSTR "searchString"
>
> Stdin via redirection FINDSTR "searchString"
>
> The various data source specifications are mutually exclusive -
>   FINDSTR can only work with one of the following: filename argument(s),
>   /F:file option, redirected input, or **piped input**.

Comment: "i want only one folder when i has been modified last" - Looks like he wants to list only the last modified folder and not just a folder with a specific name.

Answer (score 2):

This is Powershell which is included in Windows 7 and will display the most recently modified folder in a path.

```
get-childitem -path c: | sort-object LastWriteTime -descending | select -first 1 | format-table -hidetableheaders
```